# Digest Authentication - how is it used?

Tags: authentication

I understand a bit about digest authentication from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication, but I am pretty unclear on where, when or how it is used.  I can't find anything on that side of it.

Where, when and why would a webmaster use it?  Does it require any extra code on a site if the server has it implemented?

As you can see, I pretty much in the dark about how it is used, so any info would be helpful.

Maybe this could become a FAQ

Comment: John Conde closes question - people learn just that little bit less...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache server has [mod_auth-digest](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_digest.html) that implements it.    It is more secure than basic authentication and can be used in place of it.

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_digest.html):

> Using MD5 Digest authentication is very simple. Simply set up authentication normally, using `AuthType Digest` and [AuthDigestProvider](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_digest.html#authdigestprovider) instead of the normal `AuthType Basic` and [AuthBasicProvider](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html#authbasicprovider). Then add a [AuthDigestDomain](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_digest.html#authdigestdomain) directive containing at least the root URI(s) for this protection space.
>
> Appropriate user (text) files can be created using the [htdigest](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htdigest.html) tool.
>
> Example:

```
<Location /private/>
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "private area"
    AuthDigestDomain /private/ http://mirror.my.dom/private2/

    AuthDigestProvider file
    AuthUserFile /web/auth/.digest_pw
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```